# Calculate integral with dirac comb

Tags: integration, dirac-delta

Calculate integral

$\int_{-\infty }^{\infty } \! x(a\lambda +\lambda _{0} ) \delta (b\lambda +\lambda _{1} ) \, d\lambda  $

for $b>0$ and $b<0$.

$\lambda _{0}$, $\lambda _{1}$, and $b\neq 0$ are constant. $\delta$ is dirac comb and $x$ is steady signal.

**Solution:**

$b>0$
 $I=\frac{1}{b}x(\lambda _{0}-\lambda _{1}\frac{a}{b}  )$

$b<0$
 $I=-\frac{1}{b}x(\lambda _{0}-\lambda _{1}\frac{a}{b}  )$

I tried to solve this integral, but didnt have any success. Can someone tell me how to get these solutions? How much is important to understand "dirac comb" to solve this?

Comment: Use preferably \displaystyle \operatorname {III} which gives you $\displaystyle \operatorname {III}$ for the Dirac comb (it is the standard notation ; $\delta$ should be reserved for simple "Diracs".)

Comment: Did you actually want a Dirac comb or did you mean a Dirac delta?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition,
$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f(x)\delta(x)dx=f(0)$

So,

$\int_{-\infty }^{\infty } \! x(a\lambda +\lambda _{0} ) \delta (b\lambda +\lambda _{1} ) \, d\lambda = \int_{-\infty }^{\infty }x(a\frac{u-\lambda_1}{b}+\lambda_0)\delta(u)\frac{du}{b}=\frac{1}{b}x(\lambda_0-\lambda_1\frac{a}{b})
$

for positive $b$ with change of variables $u=b\lambda+\lambda_1$.

If $b$ is negative, the integral bounds are reversed when doing the change of variables and a minus sign appears.

Keep in mind Dirac's delta "function" isn't really a function but a distribution, so the integral notation is a bit sloppy for a non-physicist.

Comment: (I'm assuming it's a Dirac delta too..)

Comment: I understood 2. step. but how to get 3. from it? I tried to do first part of integral like "normal integral" but I dont know what to do with  $\delta(u)$? Is it possible to do it normal, or there are some other rules?

Comment: Once you have the integral with $\delta(u)$, since $0$ is within the bounds of the integral for $u$, you just get $f(0)$ as a result, where $f$ is simply what $\delta$ is being multiplied by. In this example, $f(u)=x(a\frac{u-\lambda_1}{b}+\lambda_0)$. Just evaluate at $u=0$.